# Change HTML placeholder picture width and height with given ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a placeholder picture, and I know the real picture's size.
For instance, my placeholder picture is 30x30, my real picture is 1200*800. But my screen size is only 600px wide.

I give the image with the real size like following

```
<img src="abc.png" width="1200px" height="800px"/>
```

But this size is wider than my screen size 600px. So I add a css like following

```
img { 
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The result is that the picture will be shown as the size 600x600. If I delete `height:auto` it will be shown as 600x800.

I want it to be shown as 600x400 with the equal ratio to the real picture. How can I do it? It is OK to use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<img src="abc.png"/>
```

and css

```
img { 
   width:600px;
   height: 400px;
   max-width:100%;
   max-height:100%;
 }
```

there is no need for a jquery.

Comment: I have a lot of images in a page with different given width and height properties.

Comment: hi @lephix then use class in the image like <img src="imageulr" class="classname"> and write the css for the classname with your width and height which your require

Comment: @lephix you can use inline styles for `width` and `height` but a class for `max-width`/`max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder must have same width/height ratio as original image. If it has other ratio, You should use JavaScript and store the original picture ratio in some variable. Then, use these informations to set value of `max-width` and `max-height` attributes (or even `width` and `height`).

BUT, if You know what width & height of your images will be, then You can set up static values in Your CSS. Like this:

```
img { 
   max-width: 600px;
   max-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Use javascript to resize the picture?

Comment: Use it to set up CSS attributes for particular image: `max-width` and `max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a static place-holder with a set Aspect Ratio to contain images with dynamic ratio's.

***Example:*** if you placeholder is 600X400 it mean the aspect ratio is 3:2
Only images with aspect ratio's of 3:2 will fit perfectly in this ex: 1200X800, 900:600

So if you have the markup`<img src="" height="100px" width="400px">`, it will work for images with the above dimensions 1:4.
But if the image is something like 800*800 it will get streached and skewed.

I would suggest the following markup

HTML

```
<img src="your src file"/>
```

CSS

```
img
{
    width:600px;
    height:auto;    
}
```

This will make the image retail its original dimensions

Answer (score 0):

So you wan't to recalculate the image dynamically to fit the screen and don't loss the images ratio right?

So you need some calculation on the image.

```
var newHeight = img.height / img.width * screenWidth;
var newWidth = screenWidth;
```

I created a demo which may help you:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4fyrLvr/)**